# Type of sorting used in comapreTo method in java, i just want to know how compareTo method works?

Tags: collections, compare

```
import java.util.*;



class Dog implements Comparator<Dog>, Comparable<Dog>{
   private String name;
   private int age;
   Dog(){
   }

   Dog(String n, int a){
      name = n;
      age = a;
   }

   public String getDogName(){
      return name;
   }

   public int getDogAge(){
      return age;
   }

   // Overriding the compareTo method
   public int compareTo(Dog d){
      return (this.name).compareTo(d.name);
   }

   // Overriding the compare method to sort the age 
   public int compare(Dog d, Dog d1){
      return d.age - d1.age;
   }
}

public class Example{

   public static void main(String args[]){
      // Takes a list o Dog objects
      List<Dog> list = new ArrayList<Dog>();

      list.add(new Dog("Shaggy",3));
      list.add(new Dog("Lacy",2));
      list.add(new Dog("Roger",10));
      list.add(new Dog("Tommy",4));
      list.add(new Dog("Tammy",1));
      Collections.sort(list);// Sorts the array list

      for(Dog a: list)//printing the sorted list of names
         System.out.print(a.getDogName() + ", ");

      // Sorts the array list using comparator
      Collections.sort(list, new Dog());
      System.out.println(" ");
      for(Dog a: list)//printing the sorted list of ages
         System.out.print(a.getDogName() +"  : "+
         a.getDogAge() + ", ");
   }
}
```

Comment: `compareTo` doesn't sort: it compares two objects.  The type of sorting depends on the method that is comparing objects.

Comment: @jeffamaphone not able to get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you have provided demonstrates how the `Comparable<>` and `Comparator<>` interfaces work. When you provide a `Comparable` type to a collection and subsequently call `Collections.sort()` on an instance of that collection, `compareTo()` will be used to determine the correct order.

Now, as is evident in the example above, `Collections.sort()` also provides an override in which you can provide an alternative comparison by passing an instance of `Comparator<>`. The method will then ignore `compareTo()` and use `compare()` of the comparator instance to determine the correct order.

The outcome of your example above will, in the first invocation of `sort()`, use the `Comparable<>.compareTo()` method to sort Dog instances according to their name, while in the second invocation `Comparator<>.compare()` will be used to sort Dog instances according to their age.

An unrelated note: It might be clearer to implement `Comparator<>` in a different class to avoid this type of confusion. The second sorting call might then be a bit easier to understand, like so:

```
Collections.sort(list, new DogComparator());
```

Comment: @loannis will get back to you after some experimentation